# Error 1004 when setting the name property of the PivotField class

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have created a macro to automate the process of building a pivot table. The macro is performing just fine, however it keeps showing me an error 1004. (however, the results are fine). I am providing the code below.

```
'PIVOT TABLE

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow12 As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Set PSheet = ActiveSheet
LastRow12 = PSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = PSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = PSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow12, LastCol)
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 16), TableName:="PivotTable1"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Destination")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.Subtotals(1) = True
.Subtotals(1) = False
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("End Date")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Trucks")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.NumberFormat = "0.0"
.Name = "Trucks"
End With
```

Comment: On which line does the error happen?

Comment: It does not give a line... It runs just fine.. And after everything is done, it gives the message box saying the error 1004 (when setting the name property of the PivotField class). No line no nothing ... thats why I cannot solve it

Comment: Why are you trying to set its name to Trucks when that's already the name of it?

Comment: good point :p ! that was the error ... thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePivot4()

Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache As PivotCache

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow12 As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Set PSheet = ActiveSheet
With PSheet
    LastRow12 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow12, LastCol))
End With

' Create Pivot Cache
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))

' Set the Pivot Table (already created in previous macro run)
On Error Resume Next
Set pvt = PSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

On Error GoTo 0
If pvt Is Nothing Then ' <-- pivot table still doesn't exist >> need to create it

     ' create a new Pivot Table in ActiveSheet sheet, start from Cell A1
    Set pvt = PSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 16), TableName:="PivotTable1")

    With pvt
        With .PivotFields("Destination")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
            .Subtotals(1) = True
            .Subtotals(1) = False
        End With
        With .PivotFields("End Date")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Trucks")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 1
            .Function = xlSum
            .NumberFormat = "0.0"
            '.Name = "Trucks" ' * Why do you need to rename it ?
        End With
    End With
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot table, with updated Pivot Cache
    pvt.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    pvt.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```